# How do I log on to my school network from my internet network at my house?

Tags: networking, ssh, telnet

Is there a way I can access network drives on the school network from my home.

Comment: Does the school have some form of VPN?  That would seem to be the best solution here, though don't forget about firewalls and other things that can be set up to block this kind of access as well as the security you've set on those shares if you have that option.

Comment: Make sure you have permission to do these things, as they'll likely set off some network alarms.

Comment: Ahem, this is off-topic.  Ask at http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a VPN, and then use Windows Remote Desktop to log on. Or, another simple solution, install Dropbox, and there's an addon for it to automatically run scripts that you put in a directory, and your scripts can copy that resource into the dropbox folder, which is automatically sycned with your account.